# 3D Projection Mapping

Tags: opengl, opencv, mapping, projection, projector

I'm trying to use a common LCD projector to shine an image onto a simple 3D shape, but do it in a repeatable way.

What I need:
My simplest example is, I place a cube on a table, place a projector attached to a tripod some distance away, measure the distance/orientation between the two (using GOM photogammetry product, http://www.capture3d.com/products-TRITOP.html ), open an existing obj (polygon) model that is exactly the same shape as the cube (dimensionally very accurate), but with some 'fancy' coloring, then project the polygon model to the LCD projector.

What I've done:
Spent a month trying to determine the intrinsic / extrinsic constants of my projector - camera pair, focal length, principle point, distortion constants... and I think I have them. (http://code.google.com/p/procamcalib/)

I've found/modified code to open my obj file.

I'm stuck with what to do with these intrinsic/extrinsic constants for the projector.

I'm using opengl / opencv...

Comment: Why?  It seems like the result would only look right if your eye/camera had the exact same position and orientation as the projector.  As soon as your eye/camera got off-axis the projected version would look progressively worse.

Answer (score 1):

Some useful links:
http://urbanar.blogspot.it/2011/04/from-homography-to-opengl-modelview.html

and 
http://cvrr.ucsd.edu/publications/2008/MurphyChutorian_Trivedi_CVGPU08.pdf

Firt when you decompose your P matrix in k,R,t where k is the intrinsic matrix and R,t are relatively the pose rotation and translation then you can generate the corresponding OpenGL matrix as follows (my solution is in C++ but you can understand the logic behind it):

```
Eigen::Matrix4d convertIntrinsicToOpenGLProjection(const Eigen::Matrix3d &K,double x0,double y0,double width,double height,double znear,double zfar)
{
    double depth = zfar - znear;
    double q =  -(zfar + znear) / depth;
    double qn = -2.0 * (zfar * znear) / depth;
    Eigen::Matrix4d proj;
    proj << 2*K(0,0)/width, -2*K(0,1)/width, (-2*K(0,2)+width+2*x0)/width, 0 ,
                           0,             -2*K(1,1)/height,(-2*K(1,2)+height+2*y0)/height, 0,
                         0,0,q,qn,
                         0,0,-1,0;
    return proj;
}

Affine3d convertExtrinsicToOpenGLModelView(const Matrix3d &R, const Vector3d &t)
{
    Affine3d MV;
    MV.linear().matrix() << R;
    MV.translation() << t;
    AngleAxis<double> adapter(M_PI,Eigen::Vector3d(1,0,0));
    MV = MV*adapter;
    return MV.inverse();
}
// Decompose P in k,R,t with any DLT direct linear transform procedure or Zhang method
Eigen::Matrix3d K; //intrinsic calibration matrix
    K <<     49.30423  ,   0.00000 ,  387.13187,
        0.00000  ,  26.81592 ,  295.07170,
        0.00000 ,    0.00000   , 1.00000 ;

    int projAreaWidth = 684; //related to the size of your screen
    int projAreaHeight = 608;
    double x0=0,y0=0;
    double zfar=0.1;
    double znear=2000;

Matrix4d P = convertIntrinsicToOpenGLProjection( K,  x0, y0,  width,  height, znear, zfar);
Affine3d MV = convertExtrinsicToOpenGLModelView(R, t);

glPushMatrix();
glLoadMatrixd(P.data());
glMultMatrixd(MV.data());

//draw your object

glPopMatrix();
```

Let me know if this makes sense for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the camera's field of view from its focal length as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view). Once you have the field of view, you can use gluPerspective() (or [do the calculation yourself](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm) - see section 9.085) to set up the perspective matrix. You'll obviously need to change the modelview matrix based on where your projector and object are, too. I don't know what distortion data you have, but you would presumably need to take that into account, too.